# Java Sql Statement Unknown column id

Tags: java, mysql, sql

My database is MySQL run from xampp
I have 3 `colums id,nazwa,kwota`
I keep getting an error:

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown
>   column 'main' in 'field list'

I think problem is with the

```
String sql = ("SELECT id, nazwa, kwota");
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```

but I was looking for almost 2 hours and does not seem to find the answer...
Im desperate, thank you

```
import java.sql.*;
import javax.sql.*;

public class JdbcDriver{

 public static void main(String args[]) {

        Connection conn = null;
        Statement stmt = null;


        String username = "wojtek";
        String password = "3445222";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/javatest";



        try{

            //STEP 2: Register JDBC driver
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

            //STEP 3: Open a connection
            System.out.println("Connecting to a selected database...");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, username, password);
            System.out.println("Connected database successfully...");

            //STEP 4: Execute a query
            System.out.println("Creating statement...");
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            String sql = ("SELECT id, nazwa, kwota");
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(sql);

            //STEP 5: Extract data from result set
            while(rs.next()){

            //Retrieve by column name
               int id  = rs.getInt("id");
               String nazwa = rs.getString("nazwa");
               int kwota = rs.getInt("kwota");

             //Display values
               System.out.print("ID: " + id);
               System.out.print(", Nazwa: " + nazwa);
               System.out.print(", kwota: " + kwota);

            }
            rs.close();
         }catch(SQLException se){
            //Handle errors for JDBC
            se.printStackTrace();
         }catch(Exception e){
            //Handle errors for Class.forName
            e.printStackTrace();
         }finally{
            //finally block used to close resources
            try{
               if(stmt!=null)
                  conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
            }// do nothing
            try{
               if(conn!=null)
                  conn.close();
            }catch(SQLException se){
               se.printStackTrace();
            }//end finally try
         }//end try
         System.out.println("Goodbye!");
      }//end main
      }//end JDBCExample
```

Comment: Your statement seems to be missing `FROM` and a TABLE.

Comment: add table name, learn how to write sql statements

Answer (score 0):

That's a weird wrong SQL statement as pointed below. It's missing `FROM table_name`

```
String sql = ("SELECT id, nazwa, kwota");
```

It should be

```
String sql = ("SELECT id, nazwa, kwota FROM your_table_name"); 
                                       ^... missing this part
```

Answer (score 0):

Table is missing in the statement. Better way is always test the query in the database editor before using it.

Answer (score 0):

We always pass SQL Statement in a `String` in java. If the Statement is Wrong the java compiler gives us an `Exception`. Same is the case with you, you have passed statement through string. But you have not specified the table from which you are retriving you data.

Your `String` is:

```
String sql = ("SELECT id, nazwa, kwota");
```

You should write the `String` as:

```
String sql = ("SELECT id, nazwa, kwota FROM table");
```

Here `table` is your `table Name` from which you are retriving your data.